# How to crash a single process in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, process

I want to analyse the outcome of my application process when it crashes. How can I manually crash a single process in Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using [kill(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) and for example signal `SIGSEGV` (segmentation violation), SIGBUS (bus error) etc. [Other useful signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) may exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send a SIGILL signal to your process :

```
 kill -SIGKILL PID
```

To get the pid of a Running-Program

syntax:

```
pgrep program_name
pidof program_name
```

You can also try this command :

```
kill -SIGKILL $(pidof processName)
```

Comment: or use "killall" if you dont have the pid, it accepts process names